# Porcelain vs ceramic tile for the whole house

Tags: flooring

I am in the process of installing new floor in my house.  I have been told by a friend that porcelain tile is a lot harder and more durable than ceramic tile and therefore better.  Another friend told me just the opposite, porcelain chips and breaks more easily than regular ceramic tile.  Also, I have been told to keep an eye on quality, but how do I know if a ceramic or porcelain tile is of good quality.  Everyone keeps on recommending a specific store, they are also one of the most expensive ones and I can not believe they are the only ones that are selling a quality product.  When buying the floor, what questions should I be asking the sales person to find out?

Comment: porcelain tile _is_ ceramic tile. see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porcelain_tile

Comment: All high fired tiles are ceramic, they just have different grades. The Porcelain end of the grade is more resistant to water penetration, usually is extruded and has had the base materials better refined and has a higher kaolin clay and quartz content. It usually also has more accurate size. If sold in the US, look for PTCA certification.